Power query Index reset if value is null
I have a data set that I need to index until there is a null value in the name and address field, then it resets the count. If it is null, the value should be zero. I'm trying to get the index to look like this:



Name and address
Index




aasdfnkjdf
1


aasdfnkjdf
2


aasdfnkjdf
3


null
0


null
0


aasdfnkjdf
1


aasdfnkjdf
2


null
0


null
0


null
0


aasdfnkjdf
1


aasdfnkjdf
2


null
0


aasdfnkjdf
1


aasdfnkjdf
2



The name and address field does not hav eany set cadence for how many nulls appear. Thanks!
I've tried doing an index, then ranking off the index, but there ar eno regular null intervals to make it work

let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name and address"}, {{"data", each if _[Name and address]{0}=null then Table.AddColumn(_,"Index",each 0, Int64.Type) else Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}, GroupKind.Local),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Index"}, {"Index"})
in #"Expanded data"


you can try this in PQ
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index.1", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each  Table.RowCount( Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index",(x)=>x[Index.1]<=[Index.1] and x[Name and address] = null))+1),
    Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom 1", each if [Name and address] = "" then 0 else if [Custom]=1 then  Table.RowCount( Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom",(x)=>x[Index.1]<=[Index.1] and x[Custom] =[Custom])) else Table.RowCount( Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom",(x)=>x[Index.1]<=[Index.1] and x[Custom] =[Custom]))-1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Custom1,{"Index.1", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"


